# Shouldn’t moment of inertia be called inertia of moment?

Tags: terminology, conventions, moment-of-inertia

Moment of inertia isn’t a moment of force, but it is a kind of inertia, so wouldn’t it be more correct to say “inertia of moment”?

Comment: Moment of = turning effect of. The turning effect of the inertia seems about right to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [questions asking why we use a particular standard notation or terminology](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4063/50583) are off-topic.